# Does Googlebot determine the value of a link by its position on the page?

Tags: seo, links, googlebot, backlinks

It's well-known that the SEO value of a website basically depends on how much it has been referenced, linked, and shared.

From Googlebot's point of view, is a link at the top of a page **more valuable** than a link at the bottom?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. But more importantly, a link within content is most important.

Any link in most any placement on the page will be good for you assuming that the site is of quality and the link has good link alt text. There is some exception to this of course. For example a link in the footer is not wise. As well, a site-wide link is also not wise. Just make sure you are not doing a Google *no no*. But links that are conversational and within content are most valuable regardless of where in the content it lies. Google does weigh a link by placement, however, the effect is minimal. So a link higher in content is best and a link before others is also best. If you have control over this, then that is good, but if you do not, just make sure it is a good link and does not violate Google's rules and do not worry about the rest.